# Multi Submit button and enter key

Tags: javascript, php

i have 4 submit button,

```
<input type="submit" name="zmianapoz" value="Zmiana Ilości" id="dodaj1" /> 
<input type="submit" name="usunpoz" value="Usunięto" id="dodaj3" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Pobranie" id="dodaj2" />
```

and this is fourth:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Aktualizuj">
```

how can i do that if i press enter key=13 then work button fourth not first on web?
i try with function onclick but probably i do something wrong

Comment: Can you show what function you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to trap the keydown event and trigger it yourself like so:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var enter = 13;
  if (event.keyCode === enter) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("dodaj4").click();
  }
});
document.getElementById("dodaj4").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("input 4 clicked!");
});
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="zmianapoz" value="Zmiana Ilości" id="dodaj1" />
<input type="submit" name="usunpoz" value="Usunięto" id="dodaj3" />
<input type="submit" value="Pobranie" id="dodaj2" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Aktualizuj" id="dodaj4">
```

Comment: ohhhh thank you guys it Works im just bored ;p its so simple i forget function eventlistener